# Increase Wordpress WXR (.xml) Import Max File Size?

Tags: wordpress, import, backup, restore

When importing a WXR (.xml) file from the Wordpress import screen under tools to pull in a backup of posts/pages/etc. it says Max File size is 8mb.  Of course most sites of size will have much larger files and I am having trouble figuring out how to increase that.

I have tried the following:

added to php.ini file:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
php_value post_max_size 50M
```

added the following to functions.php file:

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '50M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '50M');
```

added to the wp-donfig.php file:

```
define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '64M');
```

added to .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 64M
php_value post_max_size 64M
php_value max_execution_time 300
php_value max_input_time 300
```

None one of these seem to be where the limit is coming from.  Any help on increasing the limit would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying everything above to no avail I tried the following and it worked.

Create a file called .user.ini with the following and place it in your Wordpress installation folder.

```
upload_max_filesize = 64M
post_max_size = 64M
memory_limit = 64M
max_execution_time = 300
```

This is for anyone running php 5 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not work for me. It's wordpress multisite installation.

What I did is to increase `post_max_size`, `upload_max_filesize` and `memory_limit` values accroding to the @Brandon's answer.

And connected as admin of network, go to network settings and finally increase max size files value.

Comment: Multisite limit in network settings is by default 1500KB, which is the core of the issue for an MS network site.